# How can I bind the data for an asp dropdown in a Telerik GridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have this Telerik RadGrid

```
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="gvMembers" runat="server"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        OnNeedDataSource="gvMembers_NeedDataSource"
        AllowSorting="true"
        AllowPaging="true"
        PageSize="10"
        AllowAutomaticUpdates="true"
        AllowAutomaticInserts="true"
        AllowAutomaticDeletes="true"
        OnItemCreated="gvMembers_ItemCreated"
        OnItemInserted="gvMembers_ItemInserted"
        OnPreRender="gvMembers_PreRender"
        OnInsertCommand="gvMembers_InsertCommand"
        OnItemDataBound="gvMembers_ItemDataBound"
        OnUpdateCommand="gvMembers_UpdateCommand"
        OnDeleteCommand="gvMembers_DeleteCommand"

        >
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeader" />
        <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced" />
        <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="UserID" CommandItemDisplay="Top" InsertItemPageIndexAction="ShowItemOnCurrentPage">
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" ReadOnly="true" UniqueName=""></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="Valid" HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="Valid" UniqueName="valid"></telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName" UniqueName="firstname"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName" UniqueName="lastname"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="UserName" HeaderText="User Name" SortExpression="UserName" UniqueName="username"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="EmailAddress" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="EmailAddress" UniqueName="email"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="TemplateColumn" HeaderText="Role">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"
                            Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Role") %>'>
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRole" runat="server" DataTextField="Role1" DataValueField="RoleID"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridButtonColumn ConfirmText="Delete this Member?" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow"
                    ConfirmTitle="Delete" ButtonType="PushButton" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" />
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

As you can see I have an ASP DropDownList for the users role.  I now need to bind the database Role table values to this dropdown list.

I have tried using this code to accomplish this:

```
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlRole");
ddl.SelectedValue = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Role1").ToString();
```

But I get a null exception error on the second line. When I inspect the value of the DropDownList ddl it shows as null. It looks like it is not finding the DropDownList with the ID=ddlRole.  Any suggestion on what the problem may be?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer here is the code I used.

```
protected void gvMembers_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
        {
            var roles = (from c in DbContext.roles
                         select new { c.Role1, c.RoleID }).ToList();
            GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
            // access/modify the edit item template settings here
            DropDownList list = item.FindControl("List1") as DropDownList;
            list.DataSource = roles;
            list.DataBind();
        }

    }
```